# Python: How to add a static class array of objects?

Tags: python, class, dictionary

i'm a python newbie!
I'm playing with class, lists and dictionary and i have a problem!

i have this piece of code:

```
class Vacca( object ):
    Munte = dict()

    def __init__( self, nr ):
        self.nome = "VACCA_" + str( nr )
        self.numero = str(nr)
        self.mungiture = []

    def mungi( self, latte ):
        nr = self.numero
        Vacca.Munte[ nr ] = self
        Vacca.Munte[ nr ].mungiture.append( latte )

vacca = Vacca( 1 )
vacca.mungi( "white milk" )

vacca = Vacca( 1 )
vacca.mungi( "black milk" )

vacca = Vacca( 1 )
vacca.mungi( "yellow milk" )

vacca = Vacca( 2 )
vacca.mungi( "dark chocolate" )

for v in Vacca.Munte:
    print Vacca.Munte[v].mungiture
```

If i run this is the result:

```
['yellow milk']
['dark chocolate']
```

but i need this:

```
['white milk','black milk','yellow milk']
['dark chocolate']
```

what i'm wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you overwrite the object each time you do `vacca = Vacca(1)` and erase everything you've done before!

Do like this instead:

```
vacca = Vacca( 1 )
vacca.mungi( "white milk" )
vacca.mungi( "black milk" )
vacca.mungi( "yellow milk" )
```